# Issue with pymysql. Trying to use string in SELECT clause

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I am working on project using python 3.6.9 and pymysql library.
Basically I am trying to use string in SELECT clause:

```
import pymysql;

def wypisywanie_z_bazy():
    connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                                        user='root',
                                        password='',
                                        db='dbprojekt',
                                        charset='utf8mb4',
                                        cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.SSDictCursor);#kursor bez bufora, wykorzystywany ze wzgledu na slabe dzialanie serwera (sugestia z dokumentacji technicznej)
    try:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            sql = "SELECT * FROM `%s`";
            cursor.execute(sql,('Czlonek'));
            result=cursor.fetchall();
            print(result);
    finally:
        connection.close();
```

However it is not working. I have also tried doing it in a few different ways, unfortunately none of them worked.
How can I make this clause work? I tried looking into pymysql documentation but i failed.

Comment: Can you share the error message you receive and the other ways you have tried?

Comment: You cannot parameterize identifiers like table or column names. You only parameterize literal values (i.e., number constants, strings).

Answer (score 0):

You may try using an f string or a format string in the select clause as:

```
table = 'Czlonek'
try:
    with connection.cursor as cursor:
        sql = f"SELECT * FROM {table}"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
except Exception:
    pass
finally:
```

You may be exposed to sql injection!

Comment: I used it. It did not work. Nevertheless thanks for your help!

Comment: Both versions: the f string and the format string ["SELECT * FROM {}".format('Czolnek´)] work just fine, particularly if you're not exposed to sql injection. The parameterized version it's not working for table names as put it by @Parfait.